# I Get a Weird Error while Deploying a SQL Server Report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-express

When i attempt to deploy a SQL Server Report, i get the following error:

An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'OLEDB-MD' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)

This error occurs only when i try to deploy a certain report. Rest of reports are deployed successfully.

I'm deploying SQL Server 2008 Express Advanced Options.
...

Comment: what kind of data sources do you have on the report?

Comment: SQL Server ... The report is a complex sample that compares multiple sales ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLEDB-MD is for Analysis Services, right? According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365248.aspx, analysis services is not supported by SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Options.